# check content of an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to show a Toast when two `EditText` or **one of theme** is `EMPTY` to prevent app from **crashing** because of **passing a null value to the next Activity** when clicking on a `Button`>>

here is my method (Button's method) :

```
    public void mods(View view) {

    dNewBuy = Double.parseDouble(newBuy.getText().toString());
    dNewSell = Double.parseDouble(newSell.getText().toString());

    String BuyVal = newBuy.getText().toString();
    String SellVal = newSell.getText().toString();

    if((BuyVal.isEmpty()) || (SellVal.isEmpty())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ZERO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Values.this, calculator.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("valueSell", dNewSell);
        b.putDouble("valueBuy", dNewBuy);
        b.putString("flag", flag);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

`newSell` and `newBuy` are two `EditTexts` ..

the  `} else {}` part is working fine **:/**

but, it gives me this when values are empty ..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

Manifest ::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".calculator" />
    <activity android:name=".About" />
    <activity android:name=".Values"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show us your manifest please.

Comment: @PedroOliveira done

Comment: Provide the full stack trace please. There seems to be another error and you might be missing it from the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because null value can't be converted to double.

"dNewBuy = Double.parseDouble(newBuy.getText().toString());

dNewSell = Double.parseDouble(newSell.getText().toString());"

so modify your code like this.

```
public void mods(View view) {

String BuyVal = newBuy.getText().toString();
String SellVal = newSell.getText().toString();

if((BuyVal.isEmpty()) || (SellVal.isEmpty())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "ZERO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {

 dNewBuy = Double.parseDouble(newBuy.getText().toString());
 dNewSell = Double.parseDouble(newSell.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(Values.this, calculator.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("valueSell", dNewSell);
    b.putDouble("valueBuy", dNewBuy);
    b.putString("flag", flag);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if((newBuy.isEmpty()) || (newSell.isEmpty())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "ZERO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mods(View view) {

dNewBuy = Double.parseDouble(newBuy.getText().toString());
dNewSell = Double.parseDouble(newSell.getText().toString());

String BuyVal = newBuy.getText().toString();
String SellVal = newSell.getText().toString();
if(BuyVal !=null && SellVal !=null ){
if((BuyVal.isEmpty()) || (SellVal.isEmpty())) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "ZERO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Values.this, calculator.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("valueSell", dNewSell);
    b.putDouble("valueBuy", dNewBuy);
    b.putString("flag", flag);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Try this, this maybe because the strings are null